# capture button click to customize navigation

Tags: android, button, android-listview, buttonclick

Depending on the clicked `button` out of 3 `button`, different data gets populated in `listView`.

I've used this
**`onListItemClick` snippet**

```
    //ltable refers to list
    String item = ltable.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextClass.class);
    i.putExtra("name", item);
    startActivity(i);
```

Now on any button click, corresponding data gets populated in `listView`. Then on `listItelClick`, it navigates to `NextClass.class` and hence new activity gets launched.

What if I want app to navigate to next view **if and only if** `listView` is populated when `Gainers` or `Losers` button is pressed????

If `listView` is populated on `Index` button click, it **should not navigate**.

i.e. **Clicked button should be captured.**

I tried to use flag, but only **final** variables are permitted within `buttonClickListener`, so it doesn't work.

How can I implement this??

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a `class` level variable

```
boolean shouldNavigate = false;
```

and in `onClick()` of `Index Button`. set `shouldNavigate` to `false`:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   // Update adapter for Index..
   shouldNavigate = false;
}
```

But in `onClick()` of other than `Index Button`. set `shouldNavigate` to `true`:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   // Update adapter for Gainer or Losers..
   shouldNavigate = true;
}
```

and inside your `onItemClick()` check for the flag and navigate accordingly

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       if(shouldNavigate)
       {
       // you can navigagte...
       }
       else
       {
       // do other task
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the 'Index' mode, remove the `onItemClickListener`. Add it back for the other two buttons.

Comment: I missed something in question. `onListItem` click in case of Index button, it should not navigate to new activity but some other operation should be performed.

Comment: In that case have two onItemClickListeners and toggle them appropriately.